# How to get the number of hardlinks

Tags: python, hardlink

Is there some library function, or some other way, to get the hard link count of some file in Python?

Comment: Yes, and https://docs.python.org/3/library/ has all the library documentation you need.

Comment: @LutzHorn: sure, but what exactly does it return when you search for "hard links"? Things look easy when you already know where to look, but if you don't, python docs are quite unhelpful.

Answer (score 8):

Use [`st_nlink`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_nlink):

```
os.stat("foo.txt").st_nlink
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
os.stat(whatever).st_nlink
```

Not sure how this works on Windows.

Comment: It does NOT work on Windows with Python 2.7, but does work with at least Python 3.6 (from my testing on a WIndows 10 machine).

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `pathlib` (object oriented file system access)

```
from pathlib import Path


Path('foo.txt').stat().st_nlink
```